# How to encrypt with CryptoJS and decrypt with Rust Magic Crypt

Tags: javascript, encryption, rust, cryptojs

I'm attempting to encrypt a message using Javascript's [CryptoJS](https://code.google.com/archive/p/crypto-js/) like so:

```js
const encrypted_payload = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("Hello, world!", "magickey");
console.log(enrypted_payload.toString());
```

... and then decrypt using Rust's [Magic Crypt](https://docs.rs/magic-crypt/3.1.6/magic_crypt) Library, like so:

```rust
#[macro_use] extern crate magic_crypt;
use magic_crypt::MagicCryptTrait;

fn main() {
    let message = r#"U2FsdGVkX1+anrxRX8UNTJ8ur9LIf6n2YcmbmDqPSls="#;

    let mc = new_magic_crypt!("magickey", 256);

    let result = mc.decrypt_base64_to_string(&message)
        .expect("Could not decrypt base64 to string");
    
    println!("{}", result)
}
```

The `Cargo.toml` file for Rust includes:

```toml
[dependencies]
magic-crypt = "3.1.6"
```

This fails to compile. The error statement is `DecryptError(BlockModeError)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If in CryptoJS the key is passed as a string, then it is interpreted as a password and the key/IV is derived using a special derivation function (`EVP_BytesToKey`). To process the key directly as a key, it must be passed as a `WordArray`.
In the Rust code the passwords seem to be simply hashed (e.g. MD5 for AES-128, SHA256 for AES-256), which is surprisingly insecure (though I'm not a Rust expert and may be overlooking something).
Anyway this results in incompatible keys. One possibility is to use the hash of the Rust key as `WordArray` in CryptoJS:

Example: From the *magic_crypt* documentation, [here](https://docs.rs/magic-crypt/3.1.6/magic_crypt/):

```
use magic_crypt::MagicCryptTrait;
let mc = new_magic_crypt!("magickey", 256);
let base64 = mc.encrypt_str_to_base64("http://magiclen.org");
assert_eq!("DS/2U8royDnJDiNY2ps3f6ZoTbpZo8ZtUGYLGEjwLDQ=", base64);
assert_eq!("http://magiclen.org", mc.decrypt_base64_to_string(&base64).unwrap());
```

`magic_crypt` internally derives a 32 bytes key as SHA256 hash from the password. Then the encryption with CryptoJS is:

```js
var key = CryptoJS.SHA256("magickey");
var ciphertext = "DS/2U8royDnJDiNY2ps3f6ZoTbpZo8ZtUGYLGEjwLDQ=";
var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==")
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(ciphertext, key, {iv: iv});

console.log(decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

Both codes apply CBC mode with a zero IV and PKCS7 padding. Note that a static IV is insecure and should only be used for testings.

The other direction is analogous, e.g. encryption with CryptoJS generates the ciphertext from the Rust example (assuming the same key, IV and plaintext):

```js
var key = CryptoJS.SHA256("magickey");
var plaintext = "http://magiclen.org";
var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==")
var ciphertext = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plaintext, key, {iv: iv});

console.log(ciphertext.toString());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so very much! Your explanation was really well written and very helpful. ❤️

Comment: Hello! I know I'm late, but why is hashing a key considered insecure?

Comment: @EliRichardson - Using a pure digest like SHA256 as key derivation function (KDF) is insecure because it is fast. Instead, a dedicated KDF such as Argon2 or PBKDF2 should be used that intentionally delays to slow down an attacker, s. e.g. [What's the advantage of using PBKDF2 vs SHA256 to generate an AES encryption key from a passphrase?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/16354).